# Swift_TransportException Connection could not be established with smtp.gmail.com stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tls://smtp.gmail.com:587

Tags: php, laravel, email, gmail, cpanel

Recently I have been working on a `laravel` project that has functionality of sending email through smtp of gmail. So far so good with local development server but the problem arises with production server.
Error:

```
Swift_TransportException
Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com :stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465 (Connection refused)
```

**Note**: I am using shared hosting with `cpanel version 98.0.8`. I also turned on **less secure app**.

Here is my `.env` file

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=my_username@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD="My_password"
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=my_username@gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

**Again: Local development server is working properly.**

What could be a possible good solution ? Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Replace your `mail.php` inside config folder in your project as :

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mail Driver
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Laravel supports both SMTP and PHP's "mail" function as drivers for the
    | sending of e-mail. You may specify which one you're using throughout
    | your application here. By default, Laravel is setup for SMTP mail.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "mandrill", "ses",
    |            "sparkpost", "postmark", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may provide the host address of the SMTP server used by your
    | applications. A default option is provided that is compatible with
    | the Mailgun mail service which will provide reliable deliveries.
    |
    */

    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Host Port
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the SMTP port used by your application to deliver e-mails to
    | users of the application. Like the host we have set this value to
    | stay compatible with the Mailgun e-mail application by default.
    |
    */

    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | E-Mail Encryption Protocol
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the encryption protocol that should be used when
    | the application send e-mail messages. A sensible default using the
    | transport layer security protocol should provide great security.
    |
    */

    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | SMTP Server Username
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If your SMTP server requires a username for authentication, you should
    | set it here. This will get used to authenticate with your server on
    | connection. You may also set the "password" value below this one.
    |
    */

    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Sendmail System Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | When using the "sendmail" driver to send e-mails, we will need to know
    | the path to where Sendmail lives on this server. A default path has
    | been provided here, which will work well on most of your systems.
    |
    */

    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Log Channel
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using the "log" driver, you may specify the logging channel
    | if you prefer to keep mail messages separate from other log entries
    | for simpler reading. Otherwise, the default channel will be used.
    |
    */

    'log_channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),

];
```

**Step 2:**

In your gmail:

1. Go to manage your google account
2. Inside that go to security
3. Make **Use your phone to sign in** as **off**
4. Make **2-Step Verification** as **off**
5. Make **Less secure app access** as **on**

**Step 3:**

Login to chrome and then in new tab open below link:

https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

In this make press **continue** button.

Please make sure to make this recaptcha enable from you gmail account using above gmail link.

**Step 4:**

After this run below command inside your project

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

**Don't forget to make recaptacha enable.**
Try 2 to 3 times if if recaptacha is not unabled.

After this your email will be sent successfully.